# I have a numpy file that is an array of percentages, how do I turn this to a yes/no database where only values higher than 0.3 are a yes?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have an array of 19000 numbers from 0 to 1 that represent percentages and I would like to have a database of yes and no where yes is every number above 0.3 and no every number below 0.3.

Something that should look like this where original is my initial file

original = [0.2499320, 0.456484, 0.324824 ... 0.231, 0.3213]

modified = [no, yes, yes... no, yes]

Is there a way to do this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you include example input data and expected output to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I edited the post to make it more understandable, sorry I am new

Answer (score 1):

[numpy.where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) will do the job.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10)

print(arr)
print(np.where(arr>=0.3, 'Yes', 'No'))

# [0.23556319 0.1173074  0.2673033  0.05552573 0.79930567 0.33443317
# 0.88644862 0.89914459 0.64551288 0.60601345]
# ['No' 'No' 'No' 'No' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'Yes' 'Yes']
```

Comment: It gives me an error "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'float'"

Comment: It is because `list` doesn't support it, while `numpy.array` does. Cast your list to the `numpy.array`: `arr = np.array(your_list)` and here you go